# BadImageFormatException on DLL load and Provider not registered on local machine issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am running a .NET 4.0 application, [Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access) database on a Windows 7 x64 bit OS + Office 2010 (64-bit compatible provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0).

Platform target x86:

- Provider problem:

  The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Platform target *x64* or *Any CPU*:

- DLL file problem:

  System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.SHDocVw, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Comment: Is this referenced DLL compiled 32-bit?  That exception comes from cross-bitness references I think.

Comment: The Dll is 32 bit, any way to fix this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, other than obtaining a 64-bit DLL or compiling your own DLL as 32-bit, there is no way around this.  DLLs of different bitness cannot reside in the same process, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the first problem by installing the 32-bit version of the provider.  Download [is here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d&displaylang=en).

The second problem is *very* strange, an interop library should contain IL only and not have a dependency on the processor architecture.  When I create an interop DLL from c:\windows\system32\shdocvw.dll and run CorFlags.exe on it then I get this:

```
Version   : v2.0.50727
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 1
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 0
```

Note how ILONLY is on, 32BIT is off.  This should run on a 64-bit machine just fine.  I'm not close to one right now to check, try this yourself to compare.  To get a better answer you should document which version of Internet Explorer you have installed and whether you used the 64-bit or the 32-bit version of the DLL to generate the interop.  The latter is in the c:\windows\syswow64 directory.

Answer (score 1):

As I've noted in the comments, this is likely due to the fact your reference DLL is 32-bit.  I recently had this issue, you cannot load DLLs of varying bit-ness into a single process.  To get around this, you ideally need to equalise the bit-ness of the DLLs.

If that really isn't an option, you can create a new process to house the offending DLL and marshal the calls across using IPC, this however, is less than ideal.  I believe there is also a way to shim a DLL with another DLL of correct bit-ness, but likely under the hood it is marshalling cross-process calls again.

I have used IPC successfully in the past to gain access to a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit application.  Luckily for me, there wasn't anything complicated to marshal, it was basic chunky request-response semantics.

Comment: I agree, I was assuming this was the problem but was not sure. Thanks for the advice ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the build Platform target on your project for x86 as a temporary solution.